# SQL Server: Comparing against next X in group

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I know I can compare previous/next rows with `LAG` and `LEAD`, but in the comparison that I am doing; I need to be able to skip rows occasionally (but still need to acknowledge them)

Specifics: I am trying to track consults, and warm and cold transfers in a call environment. Each call has a unique key, and an ascending employee number for each stage. It also has the start and end times for each segment of the call.
A consult is defined as a call that starts and finishes before the previous non consult segment ends.
A Warm transfer is one where the end of the previous segment is after the start of the previous segment, and ends after the end of the previous segment.
A Cold transfer is a segment that starts after the end of the previous segment.

Example Data:

```
topcallid   e_created       e_terminated    empnum
EG995GIFM   16:22:40.933    16:29:51.010    1
EG995GIFM   16:25:59.827    16:27:49.027    2
EG995GIFM   16:30:07.453    16:37:44.500    3
EG995GIFM   16:38:01.677    16:59:30.777    4
EG995GIFM   16:59:46.737    17:16:48.397    5
EG995GIFM   17:04:51.243    17:29:21.620    6
```

Desired output:

```
topcallid.......TransStatus  
EG995GIFM   Consult (Stage 1 To 2)  
EG995GIFM   Cold Transfer (Stage 1 To 3)  
EG995GIFM   Cold Transfer (Stage 3 To 4)  
EG995GIFM   Cold Transfer (Stage 4 To 5)  
EG995GIFM   Warm Transfer (Stage 5 To 6)
```

Current Code, which gives every combination comparing every stage to all that follow:

```
SELECT ta.topcallid,
       CASE 
            WHEN ta.e_created < Trans.e_created AND ta.e_terminated > Trans.e_terminated THEN 'Consult (Stage ' + CAST(TA.EmpNum AS VARCHAR(3)) + ' To ' + CAST(Trans.EmpNum AS VARCHAR(3)) + ')'
            WHEN ta.e_terminated < Trans.e_created THEN 'Cold Transfer (Stage ' + CAST(TA.EmpNum AS VARCHAR(3)) + ' To ' + CAST(Trans.EmpNum AS VARCHAR(3)) + ')'
            WHEN ta.e_terminated > Trans.e_created THEN 'Warm Transfer (Stage ' + CAST(TA.EmpNum AS VARCHAR(3)) + ' To ' + CAST(Trans.EmpNum AS VARCHAR(3)) + ')'
       END TransStatus
FROM   [TransferTypeAnalysis] TA
       JOIN [TransferTypeAnalysis] Trans
            ON  TA.topcallid = Trans.topcallid
                AND ta.empnum < Trans.empnum
ORDER BY
       TA.topcallid,
       ta.empnum
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears you need a subquery to compare to the previous terminated call.  This logic assumes the terminated times are unique per call id.

```
select 
    t3.topcallid, 
    case when t3.e_created < t4.e_created and t3.e_terminated > t4.e_terminated then 'Consult (Stage ' +  cast(t3.EmpNum as varchar(3)) + ' To ' + cast(t4.EmpNum as varchar(3)) + ')'
        when t3.e_terminated < t4.e_created then 'Cold Transfer (Stage ' +  cast(t3.EmpNum as varchar(3)) + ' To ' +  cast(t4.EmpNum as varchar(3)) + ')'
        when t3.e_terminated > t4.e_created then 'Warm Transfer (Stage ' +  cast(t3.EmpNum as varchar(3)) + ' To ' +  cast(t4.EmpNum as varchar(3)) + ')'
        end TransStatus
from
    [TransferTypeAnalysis] t3
    INNER JOIN
    (
        select 
            t1.topcallid, t1.empnum, t1.e_created, t1.e_terminated, max(t2.e_terminated) previous_term_dt
        FROM 
            [TransferTypeAnalysis] t1
            left join [TransferTypeAnalysis] t2
            on t1.topcallid=t2.topcallid and t1.empnum>t2.empnum
        GROUP BY t1.topcallid, t1.empnum, t1.e_created, t1.e_terminated
    ) as t4 on t3.topcallid = t4.topcallid and t3.e_terminated = t4.previous_term_dt
```

Comment: Not sure why, but the Cold Transfer case line is being chopped by the code formatting, I didn't change the case logic, so you can use the original code

Comment: StackExchange likes to think you use HTML in answers so it can wipe out entire sections as an unknown html command

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `MAX` with `OVER` and `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING` to get the max terminated time of any preceding entry for each row.

Once you have the max previous terminated time for each entry, you can do a self join in the same way you are doing in your the current code.

**Sample Data**

```
DECLARE @TransferTypeAnalysis TABLE ( topcallid VARCHAR(20),e_created TIME,e_terminated TIME,empnum INT)

insert into @TransferTypeAnalysis
VALUES('EG995GIFM',   '16:22:40.933', '16:29:51.010', 1),
('EG995GIFM',   '16:25:59.827', '16:27:49.027', 2),
('EG995GIFM',   '16:30:07.453', '16:37:44.500', 3),
('EG995GIFM',   '16:38:01.677',  '16:59:30.777', 4),
('EG995GIFM',  '16:59:46.737', '17:16:48.397', 5),
('EG995GIFM',   '17:04:51.243', '17:29:21.620', 6);
```

**Query**

```
SELECT ta.topcallid,
    CASE WHEN TA_Prev.e_created<TA.e_created and TA_Prev.e_terminated>TA.e_terminated THEN 'Consult'
        WHEN TA_Prev.e_terminated<TA.e_created THEN 'Cold Transfer'
        WHEN TA_Prev.e_terminated>TA.e_created THEN 'Warm Transfer'
        END  + ' (Stage '+  cast(TA_Prev.EmpNum AS VARCHAR(3)) + ' To ' + cast(TA.EmpNum AS VARCHAR(3)) + ')'TransStatus
FROM
(
SELECT *,MAX(e_terminated)OVER(PARTITION BY topcallid ORDER BY empnum ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) as max_term
FROM @TransferTypeAnalysis
)TA
INNER JOIN @TransferTypeAnalysis TA_Prev
ON TA.topcallid = TA_Prev.topcallid AND TA.max_term = TA_Prev.e_terminated AND TA.empnum > TA_Prev.empnum
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ad591d/1)

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think I got your back on this one.

In your join conditions, change `and ta.empnum<Trans.empnum` to `and ta.empnum+1=Trans.empnum`

:D

Code I used to test this:

```
--CREATE TABLE #TMP (topcallid varchar(15), e_created time, e_terminated time, empnum int)
--INSERT INTO #TMP VALUES ('EG995GIFM', '16:22:40.933', '16:29:51.010', 1)
--INSERT INTO #TMP VALUES ('EG995GIFM', '16:25:59.827', '16:27:49.027', 2)
--INSERT INTO #TMP VALUES ('EG995GIFM', '16:30:07.453', '16:37:44.500', 3)
--INSERT INTO #TMP VALUES ('EG995GIFM', '16:38:01.677', '16:59:30.777', 4)
--INSERT INTO #TMP VALUES ('EG995GIFM', '16:59:46.737', '17:16:48.397', 5)
--INSERT INTO #TMP VALUES ('EG995GIFM', '17:04:51.243', '17:29:21.620', 6)

select ta.topcallid,
    case when ta.e_created<Trans.e_created and ta.e_terminated>Trans.e_terminated then 'Consult (Stage ' +  cast(TA.EmpNum as varchar(3)) + ' To ' + cast(Trans.EmpNum as varchar(3)) + ')'
        when ta.e_terminated<Trans.e_created then 'Cold Transfer (Stage ' +  cast(TA.EmpNum as varchar(3)) + ' To ' +  cast(Trans.EmpNum as varchar(3)) + ')'
        when ta.e_terminated>Trans.e_created then 'Warm Transfer (Stage ' +  cast(TA.EmpNum as varchar(3)) + ' To ' +  cast(Trans.EmpNum as varchar(3)) + ')'
        end TransStatus
FROM #TMP TA
join #TMP Trans
    on TA.topcallid=Trans.topcallid 
    and ta.empnum+1=Trans.empnum

order by TA.topcallid,ta.empnum
```

Comment: +1 will join on the next (which is what `LEAD` would do, but, if you look at the desired output, it has 1 -> 3 (as 2 is reported on, but not part of the transfer chain)

Comment: Ahh!  Sorry, I didn't catch that.  I'll try to help out tonight when I make it home from work. :)  For clarifying, you want to skip 2 in the sequence (if that's the right word) but still acknowledge it as a consult.  And this is because empnum 1 terminated AFTER empnum2 terminated?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.  It basically does the lag once to get the consults, then drops them and does it again to get the transfers, then combines the tables.

```
SELECT *
,CASE 
    WHEN lag(e_terminated) OVER (
            PARTITION BY topcallID ORDER BY e_created
            ) IS NULL
        THEN NULL
    WHEN lag(e_terminated) OVER (
            PARTITION BY topcallID ORDER BY e_created
            ) > e_terminated
        THEN 'Consult ' + cast(lag(EmpNum) OVER (
                    PARTITION BY topcallID ORDER BY e_created
                    ) AS VARCHAR) + ' to ' + cast(empnum AS VARCHAR)
    WHEN lag(e_terminated) OVER (
            PARTITION BY topcallID ORDER BY e_created
            ) < e_created
        THEN 'Cold Transfer ' + cast(lag(EmpNum) OVER (
                    PARTITION BY topcallID ORDER BY e_created
                    ) AS VARCHAR) + ' to ' + cast(empnum AS VARCHAR)
    ELSE 'Warm Transfer ' + cast(lag(EmpNum) OVER (
                PARTITION BY topcallID ORDER BY e_created
                ) AS VARCHAR) + ' to ' + cast(empnum AS VARCHAR)
    END AS StatusTemp
INTO #temp1
FROM MyTable

SELECT a.topcallID
,coalesce(b.StatusTemp2, a.StatusTemp) AS TransStatus
FROM #temp1 a
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT *
    ,CASE 
        WHEN lag(e_terminated) OVER (
                PARTITION BY topcallID ORDER BY e_created
                ) IS NULL
            THEN NULL
        WHEN lag(e_terminated) OVER (
                PARTITION BY topcallID ORDER BY e_created
                ) > e_terminated
            THEN 'Consult ' + cast(lag(EmpNum) OVER (
                        PARTITION BY topcallID     ORDER BY e_created
                        ) AS VARCHAR) + ' to ' + cast(empnum AS VARCHAR)
        WHEN lag(e_terminated) OVER (
                PARTITION BY topcallID ORDER BY e_created
                ) < e_created
            THEN 'Cold Transfer ' + cast(lag(EmpNum) OVER (
                        PARTITION BY topcallID ORDER BY e_created
                        ) AS VARCHAR) + ' to ' + cast(empnum AS VARCHAR)
        ELSE 'Warm Transfer ' + cast(lag(EmpNum) OVER (
                    PARTITION BY topcallID ORDER BY e_created
                    ) AS VARCHAR) + ' to ' + cast(empnum AS VARCHAR)
        END AS StatusTemp2
FROM #temp1
WHERE StatusTemp NOT LIKE 'Consult%'
    OR StatusTemp IS NULL
) b
ON a.empNum = b.empnum
    AND a.topcallID = b.topCallID
where coalesce(b.StatusTemp2, a.StatusTemp) is not null
```